# Devise Views Not Getting Styled in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have been working on an application for the Rhode Island State Police. I decided to use the devise gem to handle user auth. After running rails generate devise user. I went to the /sign_up page, and found that it was all there, but just as html.  For an example of my problem check out my app

http://systemsgroup2.herokuapp.com/
http://systemsgroup2.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Devise will give you plain html forms, what did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheets are referenced relative to the current path.
In your layouts (or where ever you include your stylesheets) change the paths from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style-wide.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style-wide.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much that fixed it. I starred at that code for hours and didn't catch that wow. Silly mistake thanks again!

Comment: Instead of just starting at the code, try using the inspect feature of your browser. By inspecting the broken page, it was very easy to your stylesheets were not loading from the correct path :)

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheets are not loading for the /user directory because instead of looking for assets/stylesheets it is looking for assets/users/stylesheets. To fix this you can use Rails stylesheet helper instead of manually linking to the stylesheets:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```